# Update IIS 6 WebSite Credentials via powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-6

I am trying to write a script that will loop through all of my local IIS website and update their physical path credentials whenever I'm forced to update my domain password.

The following works... the first time you run it...

```
function Set-Site-Credentials(
    $SiteElement,
    $Credentials
){  
    $SiteElement.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName = "$($Credentials.Domain)\$($Credentials.UserName)"
    $SiteElement.virtualDirectoryDefaults.password = $Credentials.Password
    $SiteElement | Set-Item -Force
}
```

After running this, I noticed that the following properties also get set

```
$SiteElement.userName #Same as was set earlier on .virtualDirectoryDefaults
$SiteElement.password #Same as was set earlier on .virtualDirectoryDefaults
```

Subsequently, anytime I try to update the credentials using the code above, these two properties remain unchanged, and the changes don't take affect in IIS.

So the result is:

```
$SiteElement.userName #Unchanged
$SiteElement.password #Unchanged
$SiteElement.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName #New value
$SiteElement.virtualDirectoryDefaults.password #New value
```

And the IIS site still shows the old username in the UI and the credentials fail.

So naturally I tried setting those extra 2 properties in my update function:

```
function Set-Site-Credentials(
    $SiteElement,
    $Credentials
){  
    $SiteElement.userName = "$($Credentials.Domain)\$($Credentials.UserName)"
    $SiteElement.password = $Credentials.Password
    $SiteElement.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName = "$($Credentials.Domain)\$($Credentials.UserName)"
    $SiteElement.virtualDirectoryDefaults.password = $Credentials.Password
    $SiteElement | Set-Item -Force
}
```

The code throws no errors or warnings, but the end result is the same, those 2 extra properties remain unchanged.

I am using the following code to get "$SiteElement"

```
$sites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
$sites | Foreach-Object { Set-Site-Credentials -SiteElement $_ -Credentials $newCredentials }
```

Also, at the end of the script I restart IIS using this command:

```
Restart-Service W3SVC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, finally found a command that works. All in all I've tried 4 different variation of the same thing from different example around the interwebz, all of which only work the first time. But this command updates properly on subsequent changes:

```
function Set-Site-Credentials(
    $SiteElement,
    $Credentials
){  
    Set-WebConfiguration -Filter "$($SiteElement.ItemXPath)/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName="$($Credentials.Domain)\$($Credentials.UserName)"; password="$($Credentials.Password)"}    
}
```

*The full script*

```
param (
    [switch]$All,
    [switch]$AllPools,
    [switch]$AllSites,
    [string]$AppPool,
    [string]$Site 
)

Import-Module WebAdministration

function Set-AppPool-Credentials(
    $AppPoolElement,
    $Credentials
){
    Set-ItemProperty $AppPoolElement.PSPath -name processModel -value @{userName="$($Credentials.Domain)\$($Credentials.UserName)";password="$($Credentials.Password)";identitytype=3}
}

function Set-Site-Credentials(
    $SiteElement,
    $Credentials
){  
    Set-WebConfiguration -Filter "$($SiteElement.ItemXPath)/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName="$($Credentials.Domain)\$($Credentials.UserName)"; password="$($Credentials.Password)"}    
}

$newCredentials = (Get-Credential).GetNetworkCredential()

$appPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools
$sites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites


if($All -or $AllPools){
    $appPools | Foreach-Object { Set-AppPool-Credentials -AppPoolElement $_ -Credentials $newCredentials }
}
elseif($AppPool){
    $poolElement = ($appPools | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $AppPool })
    Set-AppPool-Credentials -AppPoolElement $poolElement -Credentials $newCredentials
}

if($All -or $AllSites){
    $sites | Foreach-Object { Set-Site-Credentials -SiteElement $_ -Credentials $newCredentials }
}
elseif($Site){
    $siteElement = ($sites | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $Site })
    Set-Site-Credentials -SiteElement $siteElement -Credentials $newCredentials
}

Restart-Service W3SVC
```